# Increase transaction timeout in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I need to increase transaction timeout in the Orchard cms, I have one process that takes more than ten minutes, after ten minutes orchard throws timeout exception. I noticed that the default timeout is 30 minutes. I don't know how can I fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your process takes ten minute, I would strongly recommend you to execute it in another process than the IIS worker.

Furthermore, check if your transactions really need to take more than the default timeout.

The IIS workers nor the transactions are designed to be used this way.

Comment: I know that one transaction should not take a long time but in the Orchard cms every action has it's own transaction that starts when the action starts and commits when the transaction finishes and I need that transaction to save data on database. so I have to use IIS worker process and the transaction.

Comment: I update my database with the data that comes from another website.

Comment: But why does it takes more than ten minutes? I assume this is quite a lot of data. But you probably don't need a transaction running during the entire operation. Either case, I strongly advise you to use another task hosting strategy, as Orchard background tasks are not meant to perform long running tasks.